# Formatting numeric values which can also be None

Tags: python, format

I'm looking for a better way to handle optional `None` value (missing value) in a statement like this:

```
logger.info("temp1 = %.1f, temp2 = %.1f, position = %.2f", t1, t2, pos)
```

in order to prevent:

```
TypeError: must be real number, not NoneType
```

This is what I'm doing now:

```
logger.info(
    "temp1 = %s, temp2 = %s, position = %s",
    "null" if t1 is None else format(t1, '.1f'),
    "null" if t2 is None else format(t2, '.1f'),
    "null" if pos is None else format(pos, '.2f'))
    # any placeholder like "null", "None", "---", or "N/A" is fine
```

and I don't like it. Is there a better way? A solution for this small problem using `str.format` or `f-strings` would help too.

Comment: Write a helper function to do this.

Comment: @kindall Yes, that would be an improvement, but I would like to have the formatting instructions (e.g. `.1f`) in the format string - if possible.

Comment: @VPfB what version of Python are you using?  (You could use fstrings to incorporate the `.1f` "in the format string", loosely).

Comment: @jedwards Python 3.6

Comment: @VPfB added a few more options that use fstrings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a wrapper that checks itself when `__format__` is called.

```
class AnyOrNone(object):  # The wrapper is not type-specific
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __format__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.value is None:
            return "None"
        else:
            return self.value.__format__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I'm getting another error: "TypeError: must be real number, not AnyOrNone"

Comment: `__format__` is only called for new-style format strings. That means no `%` formatting. Use `"temp1 = {:.1f}, temp2 = {:.1f}, position = {:.2f}"`

Comment: Did not know that (about %). Now it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to write a simple function for this, e.g.:

```
def fin(obj): return "null" if obj is None else format(obj, '.1f')

logging.info("temp1 = %s, temp2 = %s, position = %s", fin(t1), fin(t2), fin(pos))
# INFO:root:temp1 = null, temp2 = 0.2, position = 6.8
```

Or you could write a function that would accept and format multiple arguments:

```
def fins(*objs):
    return ("null" if obj is None else format(obj, '.1f') for obj in objs)

logging.info("temp1 = %s, temp2 = %s, position = %s", *fins(t1, t2, pos))
# INFO:root:temp1 = null, temp2 = 0.2, position = 6.8
```

**EDIT:** Or, with Python 3.6+ f-strings:

```
def ff(obj, fmt):
    return "null" if obj is None else format(obj, fmt)

logger.info(f"temp1 = {ff(t1, '.1f')}, temp2 = {ff(t2, '.1f')}, position = {ff(pos, '.2f')}")
# temp1 = None, temp2 = 0.2, position = 6.79
```

or, using precision when obj is a float, and str(obj) otherwise:

```
def ff(obj, p):
    return format(obj, '.%df' % p) if isinstance(obj, float) else str(obj)

logger.info(f"temp1 = {ff(t1, 1)}, temp2 = {ff(t2, 1)}, position = {ff(pos, 2)}")
# temp1 = None, temp2 = 0.2, position = 6.79
```

where, in all cases:

```
t1, t2, pos = None, 0.234, 6.789
```

If you wanted to convert *all* floats passed as `logging` arguments that way, you could create a [custom handler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Handler.format), but that seems like overkill and prone to converting things you may not want.

Answer (score 0):

I know two ways:

```
for x in [1.23456, None]:
print(
    '1: {}'.format(x is not None and '{:0.4f}'.format(x) or 'None')
)
print(
    '2: {:{x_fmt}}'.format(x, x_fmt=x is not None and '0.4f' or '')
)
```

Out:

```
1: 1.2346
2: 1.2346
1: None
2: None
```

Comment: `cond and expr1 or exp2` is a bad idea.

Comment: Can be modified to: `'' if x is None else '0.4f'`

Answer (score 0):

My improvement of AnyOrNone class which enable custom None strings:

```
class AnyOrNone(object):  # The wrapper is not type-specific
    def __init__(self, value, missing = "None"):
        self.value = value
        self.missing = missing

    def __format__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.value is None:
            return self.missing
        else:
            return self.value.__format__(*args, **kwargs)
```